# How to share nginx log's without sudo to another user?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, logging

I have 2 users on my server. One with sudo access another without. How can i give access to nginx logs

```
/var/log/nginx/error.log
```

To another user without `sudo` permission to use `cat /var/log/nginx/error.log` ? Can i create something like a symlink to log in his /home/username directory?

So my question is - how can a user without `sudo` permission check nginx logs?

Comment: `sudo` access to what? It is not clear from your question. I know some people make 'sudo access' to mean 'root access', but that is not technically accurate. Please ellaborate.

Comment: yeah you could use `sudo` to give him the permissions actually, depending how you want to configure it.

Comment: You could use ACLs. e.g. `setfacl -m 'user:someuser:r' /var/log/nginx/error.log`. I'm not sure how that would work with logrotate. `sudo` access to cat/tail/etc the log is probably a better option anyway.`

Comment: @GregBowser IMHO, using ACLs without understanding ACLs is a recipe for problem.

Answer (score 16):

For example, like this:

`chmod 755 /var/log/nginx && chmod 644 /var/log/nginx/*.log && chmod 644 /var/log/nginx/*.gz`

this way anyone will be able to cwd and read the contents of the /var/log/nginx directory and read the *.log files.

You should also check the log rotating configuration so the permissions won't be changed again. For the last several versions of Nginx, up to and including 1.6.2, the file `/etc/logrotate.d/nginx` has used the line `create 0640 www-data adm` to set permissions when rotating logs. This should be changed to something like `create 0644 www-data adm`. It should be noted that this solution allows all users on the server to read all Nginx logs.

***Update:*** logrotate configs also should be updated to include the `su www-data adm` to allow the logadm utility to work without complaining about incorrect directory permissions.

Comment: Default Nginx configuration in `/etc/logrotate.d/nginx` is `create 0640 www-data adm`. That's in 1.6.2, but I don't think that line has changed in quite some time.

Comment: This answer is writtent so it would be universal and generic, rather than ubuntu-nginx-1.6.2-20141110-specific.

Comment: nginx config in logrotate d was resetting it. Fixed it by changing it.

Comment: Is there no other way to solve this, such when a different user tries to start nginx that it uses a different log path? I tried adding it to my new nginx.conf file but when running nginx -c newnginx.conf on this new user, it still tries to access the /var/log/nginx...